# How can I ensure Google will crawl my JavaScript state-based websites?

Tags: javascript, html, css, seo

I'm freelance web developer! I like to make one-page solution websites.

To eliminate load times between pages, and allow for fancy-dancy animated transitions, 

   **I keep all page content in `<div>`'s, initially hidden by `display:none;` CSS.**

   *I then use JavaScript to dynamically reveal the relevant content to the user.*

I am in the process of rebuilding my JavaScript state-engine for my websites, and would like to know the best way to mediate between SEO, the user experience, and development simplicity/elegance.

   I have been planning to use either `dom.com/#/state`, or follow Google's [***"Making AJAX Applications Crawlable"***](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more) guidelines, with `dom.com/#!/state` and the `?_escaped_fragment=state` business -- but it does not seem clear if this applies to my situation, and I don't want it to be a waste of time for me right now as I'm very busy.

   ***My website is not actually AJAX.*** None of my content is *'dynamically loaded'.* The content is indeed initially present on the page (no JavaScript involved), but is hidden by default by an external stylesheet.

If the down-side to my easier-and-lovely `dom.com/#/state` approach is simply that Google will index all of the content, but link it all to the homepage *(eg, `dom.com/#/state`'s content is indexed as a part of naked `dom.com/`)*, then I'm fine by that for now, because I am dealing with small websites. In the future, I plan to upgrade the system to handle the ugly `_escaped_fragment` business that Google uses to index the content for individual pages.

**Will Google be able to index my CSS-hidden page states?**

Thanks to every Stacker that reads this.

  *In appreciation of you all, I exclusively order BK Stackers from Burger King*

     //Chase.

Comment: short answer: yes, when crawling, CSS is disregarded. its just reading the HTML.

Comment: @kennypu, That isn't entirely clear cut.  Google has been known to penalize sites for hiding text.  How often this is done, I don't know, as there are certainly legitimate reasons for hiding things, and at least in my logs, Googlebot has fetched the CSS only twice all year.  Perhaps they only go through all of that extra processing when they think there is a reason?  Anyway, the point is that you shouldn't rely on this method too much.  The waters here will likely to continue to be murky, as folks do more presentation with JS.

Comment: @Brad yeah that's true, but thats to penalize spammy sites where they have keywords, etc. hidden to try to increase their rank. in this case assuming its real content, it should be fine.

Comment: I didn't realize we were referred to as stackers. I might quit volunteering my time because of that alone. But aside that, you do realize you're not reducing load times at all by doing this, right? You're probably increasing it. You should load content on demand, or at least load the relevant part of the site, then call the other content via ajax either on demand or in the background after initial load.

Comment: @kennypu, Agreed, but that's hoping that Google knows the difference (or even cares) that the site is real content.

Comment: @Brad I would assume they have a way of knowing since many sites have hidden content that appear via buttons etc.

Comment: @kennypu, There are many factors, and they change all the time.

Comment: Google probably thinks you have 1 page websites.  If you get to the point where you start loading content dynamically, you may want to look into History.js which handles AJAX navigation issues better than messing with the #.

Comment: @kennypu -- Thank you very much for your contributions, your feedback has been greatly appreciated. Your back-and-forth with Brad (who despite being snarky at first in his removed comment, provided a necessary devil's advocate) is what sold me on your comment as the answer to my question. I just wish I could give you the fatty green check you deserve! :)

Comment: @Brad -- I feel like your concerns are more fear-based than information-based. The fear is that Google has a blanket rule that will smite DHTML websites like mine unforgivingly. This is no doubt, a reasonable, and very real fear -- it's the reason I posted this question in the first place. 

Personally, after reading many Google articles on SEO and Webmaster guidelines, they do not say that hidden DHTML content like mine is forbidden. Google even mentions that hidden content that isn't misleading (and isn't otherwise violating their white-hat rules) is both fine, and acceptable.

Comment: @KaiQing -- Hahaha, maybe you're mood will shift once you have one from Burger King! Likely not XD! I understand the consequences of my DHTML technique. I select this technique, at the expense of initial site load time and multi-page indexability. When this hidden preloaded DHTML content is relatively small (like mine), the initial load time difference is incredibly negligible, making the benefits vastly outweigh the costs IMO. I love loading any heavy-enough-to-be-worried-about content dynamically with AJAX where applicable, however, this can cause the SEO issues we're all concerned about.

Comment: @dana -- That's what I've been hoping- that Google will see all of the DHTML site's content as simply belonging to a single page. So far, it looks like that is the case -- based on my own research, and everyone's invaluable feedback here on StackOverflow. Thanks for the tip on History.js. Very much appreciated :)

Comment: @chase - You can achieve multi page index with this technique as well. Just tell the page to load in the specific content for any path beyond the home page or load the page specific element first and drop the other content beneath it in the DOM to maintain relevancy. You can combine this with something like history.js to keep the urls consistent in case it's not a crawler visiting a link or something.

Comment: @ChaseMoskal Brad wasn't being snarky, what he said is true in his first comment. we were just having a discussion :)

Comment: @kennypu -- I'm afraid you must've missed his snarky-snark-snark comment that either he has since deleted, or a moderator removed as unconstructive. He must have had a bad day, as the entire comment was dedicated to mocking me, did not provide even a single sentiment or word related to the question or even web development at all, and existed purely to point out how much smarter he must be than I. Needless to say, I didn't appreciate it, and neither did the moderator or his later-sober self.

Comment: @KaiQing :) -- Indeed, with AJAX, proper multi-page indexing can be achieved with Google -- however, I don't have the time these days to implement an entire system for handling the `?_escaped_fragment` business (assuming this is what you were talking about; I may be confused). Thanks for commenting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google will be able to crawl all the HTML-Content which is on your Website.
But you have to mention some issues:

- If you want to optimize your Site for multiple Keywords. You can have
  only one Good Title for your HTML-Site. The title is very important
  ranking-signal for Google. This will make the optimization for
  multiple keywords more difficult.
- You don't have the advantage of different URLs which Google can index. Keyword-URLs are a good practice for SEO. You can/should maybe try use anchors in your page.

Some other Facts will be an potential issue as well:

- Google likes it, if you got just one  with the keywords  in it.
- Google likes your Content at the beginning and at the end of your site more than the content in the mid. (It evaluate this Content more important!)

Comment: I have chosen this answer because it answers the question, and raises some very worthwhile and serious concerns. The `<title>` and URL-keywords issue is very much worth looking into. Thanks Hayo!

Answer (score 2):

I have done a Udacity course (CS101 : Intro to Computer Science) and it tells me a lot about the algorithm used by Google to crawl webpages. So here's my answer:-
Google fetches all the HTML content of the webpages and since display:none doesn't actually "kill" the HTML it will still crawl it.